# inspect gives me \\ but put only \

Tags: ruby, escaping

why do I have different results from both puts?

```
test_string = "C:/Program Files/TestPro/TestPro Automation Framework/"
puts test_string.gsub("/","\\\\")

#result is : C:\Program Files\TestPro\TestPro Automation Framework\

puts
puts test_string.gsub("/","\\\\") .inspect

#result as desired : C:\\Program Files\\TestPro\\TestPro Automation Framework\\
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby's [String.inspect](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001153) escape all special characters, thats why you seee "`\\`" with .inspect

See String.inspect [source](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.src/M001153.html) here

```
if (c == '"'|| c == '\\' ||
    (c == '#' &&
     p < pend &&
     MBCLEN_CHARFOUND_P(rb_enc_precise_mbclen(p,pend,enc)) &&
     (cc = rb_enc_codepoint(p,pend,enc),
      (cc == '$' || cc == '@' || cc == '{')))) {
    if (p - n > prev) str_buf_cat(result, prev, p - n - prev);
    str_buf_cat2(result, "\\");
    prev = p - n;
    continue;
}
```

basically, `if c == '\'`, concatenate "`\`" to it, so it became "`\\`"

If you want double escape the backslash, you need to try with

```
test_string = "C:/Program Files/TestPro/TestPro Automation Framework/"
puts test_string.gsub("/","\\\\\\\\")

#C:\\Program Files\\TestPro\\TestPro Automation Framework\\
```

Answer (score 2):

`puts` will return first slashes as an escape symbol. Inspect won't trigger escape slashes, so it shows original string.

```
string = "\\Hello World!\\"
puts string
#=> "\Hello World!\"
string
#=> "\\Hello World!\\"
```

So if you will try this it will work:

```
puts "I am in \"Dog Bar\" now"
#=> "I am in "Dog Bar" now"
"I am in \"Dog Bar\" now"
#=> "I am in \"Dog Bar\" now"
"I am in "Dog Bar" now"
#=> SyntaxError: compile error
```

Comment: You are correct, but wording is reversed - `puts` will output string as is (i.e all escapes are parsed to produce corresponding characters on screen) whereas `inspect` will jump through hoops to re-escape all escape sequences so that they will show on screen w/o being parsed.

Comment: Yes, lost in translation :) But my idea is just the same